# Open current url without last path

Tags: javascript

**If I click on a link the page should load without the last path of the current url.**

www.test.com/category/question/test/

www.test.com/category/question/

```
<a href="javascript:jumpback()"></a>


function jumpback() {
}
```

How could this be done. I know there are similar questions, but the answers could not help me.

Comment: Alexander, so what exactly is wrong with Psi's answer that you started your bounty?

Comment: @SergGr - When the original URL ends with `/`, Psi's answer does not work: it removes only the last `/`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, if that's your only trouble, I updated the Psi's code to handle last '/' as well. I still think he deserves the bounty as the first to provide good answer. Let me know if you more troubles with his code

Comment: @SergGr - Please note that I am not the OP. :-)  Alexander may have had other reasons to start the bounty.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, Thank you. I've noticed that after I started to write that comment but before submitting it so the message in it still stands. Such a huge bounty on such a simple at the first glance question looks suspicious to me and might be a sign that the real issue is more complicated. But we need Alexander's input on that.

Comment: @SergGr I appreciate very much your intent to help me out, but I changed my answer to a more generic function (and yes, that much reputation for such a question seems to indicate despair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to strip the url manually like this:

```
function jumpback(){
    var url = top.location.href;
    var lIdx = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    top.location.href = url.substr(0, lIdx);
}
```

However, this solution ignores anything that might follow the url, such as GET-parameters, also, it will not take into account these cases, where there is no slash in the url (because you are in the document root)

If you want to cut additional parts of the url as well (such as query params), you may want to take a longer approach:

```
function jumpback(){
    var url = top.location.href;
    // cut everything from the first "?" if any
    var lIdx = url.lastIndexOf("?");
    if (lIdx >= 0)
        url = substr(0, lIdx-1);


    lIdx = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    //if the url ends with a slash (or multiples of them)
    while (lIdx == url.length){
        // ignore it
        lIdx = url.substr(0, lIdx-1);
        lIdx = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    }
    if (lIdx >= 0)
        top.location.href = url.substr(0, lIdx);
    // otherwise there is no parent directory and you are on the doc root
}
```

Another approach is to split your url into parts and ignore the last part:

```
function jumpback(){
    var url = top.location.href;
    // cut everything from the first "?" if any
    var lIdx = url.lastIndexOf("?");
    if (lIdx >= 0)
        url = substr(0, lIdx-1);

    var urlParts = url.split("/");
    while(urlParts.length > 1 && urlParts[urlParts.length-1] == "")
        urlParts.splice(urlParts.length-1, 1);
    top.location.href = urlParts.join("/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to, you don't have to use regex to remove the last part of your path:

```
  function jumpback() {
    var pathArr = window.location.pathname.split('/'); //break the path string to parts
    var lastPart = pathArr.pop(); //remove the last part
    if (lastPart === '') {
      pathArr.pop(); //if the lastPart is an empty string it might be trailing slash, so we need to remove one more part
    }
    window.location.pathname = pathArr.join('/'); //join all remaining parts together and update the pathname, updating pathname forces change in browser, so it emulates clicking on a link
    return false; //To prevent the default click
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

```
window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/?$/,"/");
```

The **path** you mentioned is located at `window.location.pathname`. What you want is to strip the last part of it, so just to replace the content after the last slash(or second last if the last character is slash).

#### From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location):

> The Location interface represents the location (URL) of the object it is linked to. Changes done on it are reflected on the object it relates to.

#### A more complicated edition

```
function jumpback() {
    var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/?$/, "/");
    if (path !== window.location.pathname) {
        window.location.pathname = path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers but to keep it simple and readable still you can give the following a go:

```
function jumpback(){
   var url = top.location.href;
   url = url.substring(0, str.length - 1); //incase there is a '/' at the end

   var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf("/");
   top.location.href = url.substr(0, lastIndex);
}
```